# how create directory from multiple parts of file name

Tags: bash

We have recently exported patient records from our old EMR system, trouble is every note for every patient came out as it's own PDF file resulting in 876,000+ PDFs in one directory, all with a long, cumbersome file name format of ID#-record#.YYYY-MM-DD HH.MM.SS.FIRSTNAME LASTNAME.TYPE OF NOTE.pdf

My first goal is to get to get all the files into patient directories labeled by ID# FIRSTNAME LASTNAME

ie: for the file labeled

```
345-1.2011-02-3 08.59.53.JOHN DOE.General Miscellaneous Service.pdf
```

a directory called `345-JOHN DOE` would be created and any files that start with `345` would be put into it.

I know I can use a script like

```
for file in ./*_???ILN*; do
    dir=${file%ILN*}
    dir=${dir##*_}
    mkdir -p "./$dir" &&
    mv -iv "$file" "./$dir"
done
```

Which in this example would take the value between the _ and ILN and create a directory on just that value. But how, if possible, can I take the ID# value and the FIRSTNAME LASTNAME value to create a directory?

Comment: I'm assuming the OS is Linux? It's important for `sed` regexes :D

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne The OS doesn't really matter.

Comment: @melpomene It would if I'm to give **sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2** (Linux sed) command and the user ran on a BSD system (OSx) 9/10 time it will throw an error saying something is not valid.

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne As you said, it's "GNU sed", not Linux sed. You can install GNU sed on other OSes (pretty much by design; when the GNU tools were written, Linux didn't exist yet).

Comment: What do you want to happen if there are files with the same ID, but a different name?

Comment: @melpomene While that's true. It's more work for the OP and I would rather give something that is compatible with the OS so it's much easier to use.

Comment: It is in fact macOS. I'm actually more wooied about the reverse: different ID#s but same name, incase there are two "John Doe s" . The ID# is unique to each patient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [use a regex](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b) like this:

```
for i in *.pdf; do
    if [[ "$i" =~ ^([0-9]+)-[0-9]+\.[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{1,2}\ [0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.([^.]+)\. ]]; then
        id="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        name="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        subdir="$id-$name"
        mkdir -p -- "$subdir"
        mv -- "$i" "$subdir"
    else
        echo "couldn't parse file name: $i" >&2
    fi
done
```

Bash (since version 3) supports the `=~` (regex match) operator in `[[ ]]`, which places the substrings captured by `( )` groups in the `BASH_REMATCH` array. This is very convenient for extracting information from formatted strings.

Note that this will effectively group files by their ID/name combination, not just ID. This means if you have files that have the same ID, but a different name, they will be put in different subdirectories.